# COM Getting INetFWMgr error

Tags: c++, com, windows-firewall

So the problem is when I try to get a pointer for that interface, it tells me `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_NetFwMgr`.

I looked into the header, and CLSID_`NetFwMgr` is declared this way:

```
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_NetFwMgr;

#ifdef __cplusplus

class DECLSPEC_UUID("304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4")
NetFwMgr;
#endif
```

So I guess I should add to my C++ libraries a *.lib file that contains a field like

```
DEFINE_GUID( CLSID_ActiveDesktop, 0x75048700L, 0xEF1F, 0x11D0, 0x98, 0x88, 0x00, 0x60, 0x97, 0xDE, 0xAC, 0xF9);
```

Ps: Im using `VC++ 6` as the compiler.

Comment: You'd normally need to link uuid.lib.  But it is very unclear what SDK you are using with such an ancient compiler.  Try  __uuidof(NetFwMgr) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. It shall be defined like this:

```
extern "C" const CLSID CLSID_NetFwMgr = {0x304CE942,0x6E39,0x40D8,{0x94,0x3A,0xB9,0x13,0xC4,0x0C,0x9C,0xD4}};
```

You could add also `__declspec(selectany)` after `const` if you want to define this `CLSID` in header rather then in cpp unit.

Comment: By the way, `DEFINE_GUID` also could be used due to `CLSID` is actually just typedef for `GUID`.